# Still Problems With Splitting an Equation

Tags: equations

I have tried using the different suggestions found in other posts on this issue, but I am still having problems. Here is my code:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\mbox{\fontsize{12.28}{21.6}\selectfont\(
y_{i} = \alpha + \beta_{1} \emph{Prime} + \beta_{2} \emph{Country} + \beta_{3} \emph{Patience} + \beta_{4} \emph{Risk} + \beta_{5} \emph{Trust} \\
& \cap + \beta_{6} \emph{Interest} + \beta_{7} \emph{Inflation} + \beta_{8} \emph{Diversification} + \gamma \emph{X}_{i} + \epsilon 
\)}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

I tried using `split`, I tried using `align` - neither worked. Here are all the packages that I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
```

Please - any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `\emph` is a text-mode command, not a math-mode command. If anything, you should use `\mathit` to denote variable names.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much - I just tried using \mathit and it worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE... Not sure why you used some unwanted tagging like `\mbox` and  `\(,,,\)` inside  `equation*`, here is the modified tags:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
y_{i} &= \alpha + \beta_{1} \emph{Prime} + \beta_{2} \emph{Country} + \beta_{3} \emph{Patience} + \beta_{4} \emph{Risk} + \beta_{5} \emph{Trust} \\
&\quad \cap + \beta_{6} \emph{Interest} + \beta_{7} \emph{Inflation} + \beta_{8} \emph{Diversification} + \gamma \emph{X}_{i} + \epsilon 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An `\mbox` cannot be splitted, you have to move `split` inside the `mathmode` part of the `mbox` and remove `&`. Now, you have two math environments (outer is `equation`, inner is `\(\)`), why not use one? Just use `\[\]` and font selection should go outside math environments.

```
\fontsize{12.28}{21.6}\selectfont
\[
\begin{split}
y_{i} = \alpha + \beta_{1} \text{Prime} + \beta_{2} \text{Country} + \beta_{3} \text{Patience} + \beta_{4} \text{Risk} + \beta_{5} \text{Trust} \\
\cap + \beta_{6} \text{Interest} + \beta_{7} \text{Inflation} + \beta_{8} \text{Diversification} + \gamma \text{X}_{i} + \epsilon 
\end{split}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Warning: When the baselines are changed just before a display, that change also affects the preceding paragraph.  There's not a one-size fits all approach to fixing that problem, but this example doesn't present sufficient information to offer suggestions.

Comment: So, I used your suggest for the split-line equation and it worked great. However, it didn't work so well for my other one-line equation. Wanting to increase the font size, I tried:
\begin{equation*}
\fontsize{12.28}{21.6}\selectfont
\[
y_{i} = \alpha + \beta_{1} \mathit{Prime} + \beta_{2} \mathit{Country} + \beta_{3} \mathit{Prime*Country} + \gamma \mathit{X}_{i} + \epsilon 
\]
\end{equation*}
This caused the equation to remain the same size while increasing the line spacing for the paragraph after. Ideas?

Comment: Change fontsize outside of mathmode, for example use `\begin{large} <math here> \end{large}` to get large font only for the math part.